# Tell rsync to not update times on files not copied

Tags: rsync

I'm apparently having trouble understand rsync’s man page.

I have a [website](https://UniGen.us) that serves pages derived by PHP from a database.

I run a cron job on the webserver that pulls records from the database and puts each in its own file.

Another cron job on my local MBP transfers those files to my local disk **if they are different.**  For this job, I tried several variations of rsync options until I finally got `rsync -rltDUvcz` to transfer **only** the file that was actually different.

Unfortunately, while it only transfers the file that changed, it sets the mod time on ALL files.  This makes it impossible for me to tell what record changed without going to the server.

**How do I make rsync update the time on a file transferred and *no other file*?**

Even better, can I update the file’s **contents** but leave the local timestamp unchanged?  That will allow me to distinguish records changed by me (I `touch` the local copy) from new records added by me or another user.